# Regular Expression - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using following PHP code

```
<?
    $data = file_get_contents('http://www.kitco.com/texten/texten.html');
    preg_match_all('/([A-Z]{3,5}\s+[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{4}\s+([0-9.NA]{2,10}\s+){1,7})/si',$data,$result);

    $records = array();
    foreach($result[1] as $date) {
        $temp = preg_split('/\s+/',$date);
        $index = array_shift($temp);
        $index.= array_shift($temp);
        $records[$index] = implode(',',$temp);
    }
    print_R($records);
?>
```

To READ the following data

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   London Fix          GOLD          SILVER       PLATINUM           PALLADIUM
                   AM       PM                  AM       PM         AM       PM
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Jun 03,2013   1396.75   1402.50   22.4300   1466.00   1487.00   749.00   755.00  
   May 31,2013   1410.25   1394.50   22.5700   1471.00   1459.00   755.00   744.00  
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What i want to do is **Read GOLD ( BID & ASK ) price** from below table, can anyone help in the regular expression changes?

New York Spot Price
                MARKET IS CLOSED
            Will open in

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Metals          Bid        Ask           Change        Low       High 
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Gold         1411.20     1412.20    +22.90  +1.65%    1390.10  1418.00 
   Silver         22.74       22.84     +0.48  +2.13%      22.26    23.08 
   Platinum     1495.00     1501.00    +41.00  +2.82%    1470.00  1511.00 
   Palladium     756.00      761.00     +7.00  +0.93%     750.00   766.00 
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Last Update on Jun 03, 2013 at 17:14.58
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you could come up with the first expression, the second one shouldn't pose any problems.

Comment: Is the table data in plain text or HTML? This will make a difference with constructing a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm only matching the numbers and period character. This code should return the numbers you're looking for. It uses your data string from your example.

```
<?
preg_match_all('!Gold\s+([0-9.]+)\s+([0-9.]+)!i',$data,$matches);

//New York
$ny_bid = $matches[1][0];
$ny_ask = $matches[2][0];
print("NY\nbid: $ny_bid\n");
print("ask: $ny_ask\n\n");

//Asia
$asia_bid = $matches[1][1];
$asia_ask = $matches[2][1];
print("Asia\nbid: $asia_bid\n");
print("ask: $asia_ask\n");
?>
```

**Output**

```
NY
bid: 1411.20
ask: 1412.20

Asia
bid: 1406.80
ask: 1407.80
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you could modify your existing regex to match both tables easily, but if you had the second table in a string, you could use:

```
$string = "PLAIN TEXT TABLE DATA HERE";

preg_match('/Gold\s+(\d+\.\d{2})\s+(\d+\.\d{2})/',$string,$matches);

$goldBid = $matches[1];
$goldAsk = $matches[2];
```

Comment: i tried to change the code but it doesnt show any record its blank ? please check it at http://dev1.edisbest.com/test.php

Comment: The OP is probably using their original `$variable` name instead of `$string`. I tested on my server and this method also works.

Comment: OP: are you trying to read the data in HTML or is it plain text?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com)

```
<?php
pattern('Gold\s+([0-9.]+)\s+([0-9.]+)', 'i')->match($data)->forEach(function ($m) {
    print 'bid: ' . $m->group(1);
    print 'ask: ' . $m->group(2);
});
```